# Given that the equation, $(k-1)x^2-2(k-1)x-(3k+1)=0$ has real roots, show that $k^2-k≥0$

Tags: roots

I can get to $k^2-k≥0$ but only when I make $b^2$ negative. The problem is why would I make $b^2$ negative other than the fact that $b$ is negative in the original equation? The problem with this is that $c$ is also negative and so I would also have to make c negative which gives me $8x^2-8≥0$

Help me please, regards

More information: This is Question 9(b)(ii) from Past Exam Paper AQA Mathematics A Level Unit Further Pure 1 June 2013

Comment: Are you sure to have written the right equation?

Comment: Ah this makes more sense than "equal" roots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if the discrimiant is positive. The discriminant of $ax^2 + bx +c$ is $b^2 -4ac$. In your case $a= (k-1)$, $b = -2(k-1)$ and $c = -(3k+1)$.

Thus you need to check if the following is positive: 
$$ 
(-2(k-1))^2 - 4(k-1)(-(3k+1)) = (2(k-1))^2 + 4(k-1)(3k+1).$$
Simplifying this will yield something directly equivalent to your condition.

Pay attention that the formula is given for $ax^2 + bx +c$, if you have minuses in the expression they need to be taken into account when determining the $a,b,c$. 
In case you find this difficult, rewrite the same expression introducing the pluses to make this more clear.

Comment: So -(2(k-1)) is not the same as (-2(k-1)) ? I think I am getting confused by the square function and how it actually applies to that negative

Comment: No $-(2(k-1))$ is the same as $(-2(k-1))$. What I meant to highlight is that the squaring makes the sign disapear. So for $b$ it would not even change anything if *in error* you took $b=2(k-1)$. But the error of taking $c= 3k-1$ has an effect.

Comment: Having looked at your other comment it might be that you calculated the square of  $-2(k-1)$ in a wrong way as $-4(k-1)^2$, yet it is $4(k-1)^2$. Note that $b^2 = (-b)^2$ yet $-b^2$ is something else. In now think this is what you meant in your first comment here. For example, $3^2 = (-3)^2 = 9$ but $-3^2 = -9$. So while $(-3)$ and $-3$ are the same thing. $(-3)^2$ and $-3^2$ are not.

Comment: Something which is also confusing me, why is c=-(3k-1) rather than c=-(3k+1)

Comment: Sorry this was my error! I correct it.

Comment: Can you show your working? How does the -4(k−1)(−(3k+1))=4(k−1)(3k+1)

Comment: Sure. It is basically that $-(-x)=x$, note $-4(k−1)(−(3k+1))= -4(k−1)(−1)(3k+1) = -(−1)4(k−1)(3k+1) =4(k−1)(3k+1)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be -4(k-1)((-1)(3k+1))? In which case you would have to multiply ((-1)(3k+1)) first?

Comment: Multiplication is associative so this does not make an actual difference. One thus also does not typically write all the parenthesis only those that are relvant.

Comment: If -4(k−1)(−(3k+1))=4(k−1)(3k+1) then does this also mean -4(k−1)(−(3k+1))=-4(k−1)(3)(−(k+1)) considering -4(k-1)((-1)(3k+1))=-4(k-1)(-1)(3k+1)

Comment: No. You because $3k+1$ is not the same as $3(k+1)$ the latter is $3k + 3$ by the distributive law.

Answer (score 2):

A quadratic equation with real roots has discriminant $ \geq 0$. Here we have
$$
0 \leq D = 4(k-1)^2 + 4 (k-1)(3k+1) = 4(k-1)(4k) = 16k(k-1),
$$
implying $k^2 - k = k(k-1) \geq 0$.

Comment: I had put the negative outside the bracket like this, -(2(k-1))
But I am still kind of confused as to why this would make a difference since -1 squared is 1?

Comment: If the equation is $ax^2+bx+c$, we have $b=-2(k-1)$. So $b^2 = (-2(k-1))^2 = (-1)^2(2)^2(k-1)^2 = 4(k-1)^2$.

Comment: How did you get +4(k−1)(3k+1) when substituting a and c into -4ac?

Comment: $a=k-1$, $c=-(3k+1)$, so $-4ac = -4 \cdot (k-1) \cdot (-(3k+1)) = 4 (k-1)(3k+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $k=1$ would turn your equation into $-4=0$ for all $x$ so we may suppose that $k\neq 1$. In this case, the given equation is equivalent to:
$$
0=x^2-2x-\frac{3k+1}{k-1}=x^2-2x-\frac{-k+1+4k}{k-1}=(x-1)^2-\frac{4k}{k-1}.
$$
This is solvable for real $x$ iff $4k/(k-1)\geq 0$. Multiplying this last inequality by $\frac{(k-1)^2}{4}>0$ gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate its  discriminant and set it to zero.

$ 4(k-1)^2 + 4 (k-1)(3k +1) = 4\,(k-1)*4k  = 16\,k\,(k-1) $

Graph of $ y(k)  = k(k-1) $ is a parabola with roots k = 0,1. The portion $ 0 < k < 1 $ lies above x-axis and that part only gives real roots.